# Query performance after creating views in HIVE using get_json_object?

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

Does Hive get_json_object function parse each JSON object for field resolution, even after we create a view on top of JSON data?

We are having issues reading our JSON Data with SERDE. For this reason we want to use this udf and create views on top of data.

Problem is about a concern that queries on data may be slow in future using this path.

It will be helpful if creating a view on top of hive table will parse the data only once at the time of View creation.

Does Hive Support this or not?

Any ideas from Hive experts on this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Hive does support views. If you're worried about the speed of it, though, you could load `impala` instead. It uses the same metadata and tables as `hive`, but is substantially faster for user querying.

Comment: We created View on top of data. Every thing looks good. My question is....is hive going to do get_json_object field parsing and resolution for every query i write on the view from now or not?

Comment: Dont know, not an expert, sorry. All I know (?) is that Hive does map reduce on any query, so it makes it bloody slow but good for batch jobs. Impala is great for regular SQL use

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of view is to hide complex query from user.Let say you did some complex join query to get all sales data.Now you want your end user to fire query like select * from sales to get all sales data so in that case you can go for view. Whenever you use view in query it will run map reduce job for that view.So it do not make any improvements for speed.

Regarding your question one way to get rid of issue is to store all parse data to another table if possible and then fire queries.It will reduce cost of calling serde every time. I've followed this approach for weblogs.